# How to install apt-get

Tags: linux, apt

I checked my OS install using this command

```
uname -a
```

and got this result

```
Linux uc3-dev 2.6.32.27-0.2-default #1 SMP 2010-12-29 15:03:02 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am on a new server box, so I think apt-get was just not installed.  What is the best way for me to install apt-get?  By the way I have all the admin privileges.

**Here is the output of lsb_release -a**

If 'lsb_release' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:

```
command-not-found lsb_release
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `lsb_release -a` ?

Comment: What is the output of 'cat /etc/lsb-release'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`apt-get`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) is a package management tool introduced by Debian and also used by other distributions such as Ubuntu. Googling on your exact kernel version suggests that you have [OpenSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE). That's a different Linux distribution. You'll want to start with [YaST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YaST) and perhaps check out [Zypper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZYpp) for package management.

Comment: actually I have Seleste Linux.  Not sure if that clarification makes any difference :)

Comment: @Genadinik: Neither I nor Google have heard of Seleste Linux, but by the looks of it, it's based on SuSE.

Comment: Here is the official name: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES).  Obviously I am a total newb in this flavor of Linux :)

Comment: @Genadinik Gilles's answer is correct then, SLES uses YaST or Zypper to install and manage packages. Follow the links he posted or search online for their usage. Here's a good link I found after a quick search: http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage_11.3